# View config not found for name RNCSafeAreaProvider

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to bring React Navigation Tab navigation into my project but get the titled error when adding the NavigationContainer. It seems to specifically be when I add the instance of the component, not the import of NavigationContainer or definition of the different screens. Here's the real kicker, the error is always listed at line 33 no matter what code is on that line. I can add additional returns to make line 33 a blank line and it still shows there. It just so happens this falls within one of the screen functions, but even if I add a bunch of returns to push it above that into the imports, it's still at line 33.

I am using snack.expo.io. I've noticed the error doesn't occur when using the web emulator (is that even an emulator?) but it does occur for the iOS and Android emulators. I copied in the dependencies that worked for the sample code from React Navigation, but I'm not confident in them. I just know I have the tab navigation working in a simpler app (it's really just their example).

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-svg": "10.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg-image": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.13",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.13"
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import SVGImage from 'react-native-svg-image';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import ExerciseButton from './components/ButtonExercise';
import NavigationButton from './components/ButtonNavigation';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 90 }}>{/*Usable Space Container*/}

        {/*Timer*/}
        <View style={styles.timer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
            <Text>Pause</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.timer}>4:57</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Options</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/*Information Area*/}
        <View style={[styles.fillCenter]}>
          <View style={[styles.fillCenter, { flexDirection: 'row' }]}>
            {/*Upper Left*/}
            <View
              style={[
                styles.fillCenter,
                styles.infoAreaQuad,
                { backgroundColor: 'red' },
              ]}>
              <Text style={styles.infoAreaQuad}>1</Text>
            </View>
            {/*Upper Right*/}
            <View
              style={[
                styles.fillCenter,
                styles.infoAreaQuad,
                { backgroundColor: 'yellow' },
              ]}>
              <Text style={styles.infoAreaQuad}>2</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={[styles.fillCenter, { flexDirection: 'row' }]}>
            {/*Lower Left*/}
            <View
              style={[
                styles.fillCenter,
                styles.infoAreaQuad,
                { backgroundColor: 'green' },
              ]}>
              <Text style={styles.infoAreaQuad}>3</Text>
            </View>
            {/*Lower Right*/}
            <View
              style={[
                styles.fillCenter,
                styles.infoAreaQuad,
                { backgroundColor: 'blue' },
              ]}>
              <Text style={styles.infoAreaQuad}>4</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        {/*Alternate Options*/}
        <View style={[styles.buttonRows, { flexDirection: 'column' }]}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons}>
            <Text style={styles.centeredTextSmall}>Roll Again</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons}>
            <Text style={styles.centeredTextSmall}>Pick Specific Exercise</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/*Exercise Buttons*/}
        <View style={styles.buttonRows}>
          <ExerciseButton ButtonText={'Squats'} />
          <ExerciseButton ButtonText={'Lunges'} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonRows}>
          <ExerciseButton ButtonText={'Pushups'} />
          <ExerciseButton ButtonText={'Chin Ups'} />
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function TestScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Test!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonRows: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  buttons: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
  },
  fillCenter: {
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  infoAreaQuad: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  timer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'stretch',
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});
```